# How to run Selenium tests parallely (having dependency to few Physcial Network devices, controlled through separate web-Ui) using TeamCity Agents/ CI

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit, parallel-processing, teamcity, cucumber-jvm

**Running Selenium tests having dependency to few Physical Network devices, parallely using TeamCity / CI.**

Hi Guys,

I would like to run Selenium Cucumber tests JAVA-Maven using TeamCity;

We could create few maven profiles, which in turn calls set of Cucumber Test Runners.

Could you please suggest how we can achieve parallel execution using TeamCity Instances / multiple TeamCity nodes, which will correspond to categories of mentioned bespoke devices.

Without TeamCity mulitiple instances I would achieve this in following way:

> Create Set of Cucumber Test Runners
>   Categorise them based on type of devices
>   Call the test runners using Maven profiles
>   Achieve the parallelism using maven-surefire plugin.
>   Maintain the active set of devices using runtime JSON file / POJO.

But kindly advise how to achieve this using TeamCity multiple agents / instances.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

No idea how to do this in TeamCity specifically, but you may find this of use, which is a general way to run Cucumber-JVM tests in parallel using Maven. This will open multiple browsers on the same machine.

https://www.opencredo.com/2013/07/02/running-cucumber-jvm-tests-in-parallel/

If you wish to run Selenium tests across multiple machines, it sounds like what you are looking for is [Selenium Grid](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2).

Answer (score 0):

My team solved the parallelization problem by using a tool that we developed and pushed to github called [Zucchini](https://github.com/Comcast/zucchini).  It handles the multithreading, local thread variables, and synchronization (should you need that) and has helped us scale out our tests for web, mobile and STBs nicely (especially when paired with SauceLabs)